# Cannot use manage.py because of uwsgi import in settings.py

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, manage.py

I use django 1.8 + uwsgi + nginx on my production server. uwsgi is in emperor mode. I import the uwsgi python module in myapp/settings.py to enable autoreload upon code modification. As I understood, this python module is available for import only when the python thread is spawn by a uwsgi worker. When I try to use manually manage.py collectstatic, is imports settings.py and then fails to import uwsgi.py.

Is there a way I use the uwsgi python module while still being able to use manage.py ?

The code I use to enable autoreload (in myapp/sttings.py):

```
import uwsgi
from uwsgidecorators import timer
from django.utils import autoreload

@timer(3)
    def change_code_gracefull_reload(sig):
    if autoreload.code_changed():
        uwsgi.reload()
```

Comment: haha, I know where that came from.  Credit is due!!! http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/TipsAndTricks#uWSGIdjangoautoreloadmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to catch the `ImportError` exception and pass.

```
try:
    uwsgi
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Alternatively, you could use a different settings file for your production server. This would import the settings from your regular `settings.py` file, and include the import and code for autoreload.

Comment: You can use the [`--settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings) option to specify a different settings file to use when running `manage.py`, or use [`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) to specify a different module when deploying with uwsgi.

Comment: Eventually, the second solution is the one I prefer. [A lot of flavors here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings)